# Relationship between different parts in GWT

Tags: gwt

What is the recommended relationship between different parts in GWT, if there is any, to build up the generated view? I mean in a one-one, one-many, many-many way to speak for Widget, View (XML and Java) and Activity to result in a generated js/html file?

It is a quite abstract question without any specific case, but I am trying to understand how GWT app can be designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post helped me a lot to understand how Views, Activities, Places etc is connected to build an app that is other than a simple Hello World.

http://blog.vivavivu.com/2010/11/think-in-gwt-mvp-framework-activities.html